# Plot Multiple bar chart with condition

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a multiple bar chart that shows the distribution of income according to the 'Marital_Status'

```
              ID  Year_of_Birth Highest_Qualification Marital_Status   Income  \
     0      5524           1957            Graduation         Single  58138.0   
     1      2174           1954            Graduation         Single  46344.0   
     2      4141           1965            Graduation   Relationship  71613.0   
     3      6182           1984            Graduation   Relationship  26646.0   
     4      5324           1981                   PhD   Relationship  58293.0
     ...
```

I tried it with seaborn

```
   sns.displot(df['Income'], bins = 20, x=bin, hue = "Marital_Status", kde = False, multiple="stack")
   plt.show
```

But it didn't work.

```
    Could not interpret value `Marital_Status` for parameter `hue`
```

This was the most promising idea I had, but I don't get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in setting `data` argument of `sns.displot` to `df['Income']`. Seaborn needs to know that there are other columns to correctly plot the distribution of `Income` according to `Marital_Status`. Please checkout the [documentation of Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot) for more details.

Your question can be solved using `seaborn.histplot`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_data = {"ID": [5524, 2174, 4141, 6182, 5324],
        "Year_of_Birth":[1957, 1954, 1965, 1984, 1981],
        "Highest_Qualification": ['Graduation'] * 4 + ['PhD'],
        "Marital_Status":["Single"]*2 + ["Relationship"] * 3,
        "Income": [58138.0, 46344.0, 71613.0, 26646.0, 58293.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=input_data)

sns.histplot(data=df, bins = 20, x='Income', hue = "Marital_Status", multiple="stack")
plt.show()
```

[image]

It can be also solved using `seaborn.displot` (call `displot` instead of `histplot` in the above code) :

```
sns.displot(df, bins = 20, x='Income', hue = "Marital_Status", multiple="stack")
```

This gives:
[image]